# C# to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

Is it possible to run C# with SQL Server locally without intalling SQL Server on my computer ?
I mean, does it exist a library that can be loaded in VS 2010 for example to let run connection to SQL Database without having to install all packages for SQL Server?

Comment: Are you looking specifically for Microsoft SQL Server, or any SQL database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider [SQL Server Compact](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlce), an embedded database that lets you generate it in run-time so no pre-installation of SQL server is needed.

Comment: I read SQL Server Compact is for Web application (ASP.NET) not desktop (C#)

Comment: The latest version is SQL Server 2012 Compact Edition: http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/2012-editions/compact.aspx

Comment: @DeathCoder: There's no reason you can't use it in a desktop application.

Comment: @DeathCoder, read "Compact is a free, embedded database that software developers can use for building ASP.NET websites and Windows desktop applications."

Comment: Just be cautious that the maximum size of the database file is 4GB.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully used DataSets and AtaTables to create an in memory database in the past, for what it's worth. This does not require installing any SQL server or components.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Server Express LocalDB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx) is the "new" way of providing a local SQL Server database for a standalone application.